# Basic Authentication for a rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, api, authentication

I am developing a simple api which will be used by iphone.  Is there a simple authentication  gem (with token authentication or api key) in rails which I can use over http(No https). Some thing like Devise with token_authentication enabled.

Comment: Are you using [rails-api](http://blog.wyeworks.com/2012/4/20/rails-for-api-applications-rails-api-released)?

Comment: No, I am not using that.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

you can simply add http basic auth support by adding following to application controller

```
before_filter :http_basic_authenticate

def http_basic_authenticate
  authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic do |username, password|
    username == "1username" && password == "password1"
  end
end
```

then try

```
curl http://yourdomain.com
=> HTTP Basic: Access denied.

curl --user 1username:password1 http://yourdomain.com
=> result .....
```

Comment: problem with this is that. client will sent username and password in plain text.

Comment: yes, so lets say, you are client, how would you like to get authenticate? ...what will you pass on, an encrypted string which is not readable ...but still its a plain text

Comment: I need a gem that would create a token or a api key whose validity will be for the next seven days. The app will use this token or api key to authenticate its request.

Comment: would love to see such feature with [rails-api](https://github.com/spastorino/rails-api) ..where we can set security on/off, we can config auth token expiry :) @carlos-antonio

Comment: We would build a website also for this in the same application though we started off with an api.

Comment: perhaps you need to manage it your-self for now, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7649560/rails-expire-password-within-24-hours) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7649560/rails-expire-password-within-24-hours) may help you

Comment: Abhay Kumar, using HTTPS will eliminate those risks

Comment: If you're doing the username and password comparison on your own like in the given code example, you'll want to use `ActiveSupport::SecurityUtils.secure_compare` to thwart timing attacks