# devise how to redirect to edit password

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using Devise for my rails project. I want to redirect a user to password reset screen if password is 6months older. how to redirect to devise edit_user_password_path?

Please help me.

Comment: there is useful command `rake routes`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try [phatworx / devise_security_extension](https://github.com/phatworx/devise_security_extension) which has a `password_expirable` module, define this in your model and have a read over the documentation for the options.

Alternatively [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7649560/rails-expire-password-within-24-hours) may help!